# Which Windows TeX package goes well with TexMaker ?

Tags: installing, texlive, miktex, windows, texmaker

I'm trying to setup my Windows 7 box with LaTeX. I had installed TexMaker 3.0, but I later found out I had to install a TeX Package (like MikTeX/TeXLive) *before* installing TexMaker.

My question is very simple - for a normal day-to-day use (writing papers/formatting CVs), which is the best Windows implementation that works with TexMaker on Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MikTeX and TeXLive are not TeX *packages* but *distributions*. Both implement basically the same compilers. Both take the packages (the files you include with `\usepackage`) from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org). These are independent from the distributions. However, some (newer) packages might be not (yet) included in one distribution. But there should not be any difference for "normal day-to-day use".

What is different between these two distributions is how they allow you to update packages, i.e. which user interface they give you in addition to the normal (La)TeX compilers. MikTeX for example allows the automatic installation of missing packages on-the-fly. AFAIK it is also more optimized towards Windows users. TeXLive is provided for other OSs as well and is therefor less Windows specific. You might want to use MikTeX on Windows because of that. TeXMaker should work fine with both.